# JSR 303 Bean Validation in java SE or inside jaxb

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb, bean-validation

I receive xml and convert it to bean via jaxb. I need to validate xml and I don't want to use xsd or other xml validation methods. I like to use annotations and bean validation methods. How can I validate bean in java se environment? But the best solution is implement JSR 303 validation in jaxb framework

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

I initially interpreted the question as "how do I make JAXB schema-derived classes JSR 303-validatable". After the discussion in appeared that the OP had a different question. Still, I'll leave my answer as I think it may be helpful for other people who find this question via keywords.

But it is not the answer to OP's question, sorry for this.

---

Please see the [`krasa-jaxb-tools`](https://github.com/krasa/krasa-jaxb-tools) `Jsr303Annotations` plugin.

> Generates:
>
> - @Valid annotation for all complex types, can be further restricted to generate only for types from defined schema:
>     -XJsr303Annotations:targetNamespace=http://www.foo.com/bar
> - @NotNull annotation for objects that has a MinOccur value >= 1 or for attributes with required use
> - @Size for lists that have minOccurs > 1
> - @Size if there is a maxLength or minLength or length restriction
> - @DecimalMax for maxInclusive restriction
> - @DecimalMin for minInclusive restriction
> - @DecimalMax for maxExclusive restriction, enable new parameter (inclusive=false) with: -XJsr303Annotations:JSR_349=true
> - @DecimalMin for minExclusive restriction, enable new parameter (inclusive=false) with: -XJsr303Annotations:JSR_349=true
> - @Digits if there is a totalDigits or fractionDigits restriction.
> - @Pattern if there is a Pattern restriction

Answer (score 2):

I cant understand how can I run krasa-jaxb-tools, I found another solution. It is hibernate-validator
dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

and java code:

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
x = validator.validate(bean).size(); // x=0 good; x!=0 bad
```

it is not beautiful but it is works

Comment: Ok, then it's a different story. This was not evident, sorry.

Comment: I've updated my (non-)answer to avoid misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation.
I developp REST services with Java 7, Jax-RS (cxf), Spring (core), within a servlet container (Tomcat 7).
I don't have a persistance layer (it's a search backend based on Lucene/Solr), I don't use any managed environment (except Spring for DI).

I had a pojo class (MyPojo) and I created a constraint (MyPojoConstraint) and its underlying validator (MyPojoValidator).

Note: the pojo instances are not created via Spring
Note: the constraint is a class level constraint

So, MyPojo is someting like:

```
@MyPojoConstraint
public class MyPojo {

// members

// getters/setters
}
```

At the beginning, I thought putting the @MyPojoConstraint annotation would be enough/magic (i.e that when creating an instance of the class, the validation will be done).

But nothing happened. I tried using the @Valid annotation, using it on the constructor. But it did not work.

I ended up writting this kind of code:

```
MyPojo p = new MyPojo(....);

// Proceed to validation
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<SuggestMRRequestParameters>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(p);
if(constraintViolations.size() > 0){
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(constraintViolations);
}
```

My understanding now is:

- if you have "managed beans" (via Spring or an entity manager) whose
  lifecycle is managed by a container, then this container will take
  care of executing the validation
- if you have only pojo / unmanaged beans, you have to programatically execute the validator: in some context, I guess AOP could be usefull to do this and avoid writing too much boilerplate code

I will greatly appreciate if someone can confirm my understanding or correct me if I'm wrong

Thanks

Philippe